# What is the structure of GaAs?

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

Ga has three valence electron, and As has five valence electron. How do they share electrons so that each has 8 valence electrons? Does each Ga atom share 5 electrons with 5 different As atoms?

Comment: This question might be better answered in physics.SE. This is not about electronic design.

Comment: You may find this helpful https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/how-many-ga-atoms-are-connected-to-one-as-atom-in-solid-gallium-arsenide

Comment: @mhaselup Very nice catch!